# Custom UICollectionView of UIImages error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiimage, uicollectionview

This is the first time I have ever tried to make a UICollectionView before, I have an ImageArray that is being read from coreData.. all of the images are NSData I am reading them into a UIImage... I would then like to display the UIImage into a UICollectionView that I allow the user to select from to update a preview view.

I have added these 3 delegates to my class.

And these are the delegates I have implemented.

```
// add collectionView
photoCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 50.0, 200.0, 700.0)];
    [photoCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell"];
    photoCollectionView.dataSource = self;
    photoCollectionView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:photoCollectionView];


//..

#pragma mark - CollectionView Delegates
#pragma mark -- UICollectionView Datasource
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [imageArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;
}


#pragma mark -- UICollectionView Delegate
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // TODO: Select Item
}
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // TODO: Deselect item
}


#pragma mark –- UICollectionViewDelegate FlowLayout


- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *currentPhotoDict = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *imageForCollection = [UIImage imageWithData:[currentPhotoDict objectForKey:@"DImage"]];

    //show image in collectionview?

}


- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 20, 50, 20);

}
```

When I run this code above I am receiving the following error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

Comment: Show the code where you are actually creating the collection view. That is what the error is about.

Comment: Is that not what I am doing at the top of the view? Sorry like I say first time on this viewcontroller train.. im trying to figure it out as I go...

Comment: have you registered a cell with an identifier? and why are you saving images in core data?

Comment: @HurkNburkS ah yes sorry. Will answer...

Comment: @vin the images are being sent to a server at some point during the applications life cycle then deleted from the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is stating that you need to create the collection view with a non-nil layout object.

You need to use...

```
photoCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 50.0, 200.0, 700.0) collectionViewLayout:someLayoutObject];
```

You need to create the layout object first too.

Possibly just use...

```
photoCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 50.0, 200.0, 700.0) collectionViewLayout:[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init]];
```

Comment: okay this second line of code worked.. however I now need to know how to show the image.. any chance you know of how to do that?

Comment: Well you'll need a custom UICollectionViewCell. Have you ever used a custom UITableViewCell? It's just the same.

Comment: yup, I have used one of those! do I need to worry about the layout of the cells in the collection view somehow?

Comment: I think you need to start from the beginning... Take a look here. http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12 This is a very good tutorial about how to use UICollectionView.

Comment: okay I have actually started that and I thought that the cell part was being done in InterfaceBuilder but now that I look at it I see that its actually a cell class with an .xib so I will read over that part again thanks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with doing stuff in interface builder and in a lot of cases (like this) using a storyboard and interface builder can actually make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify kind of layout you want to use when you initialise collection view:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
photoCollectionView =[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 50.0, 200.0, 700.0) collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

Comment: You should use it when you add collection view. Note that the second line it's first line of the code you added in your answer.